# How to ignore all SSL errors?

Tags: qt, ssl, websocket

Trying to ignore:

```
The host name did not match any of the valid hosts for this certificate
```

Using this code before the `QWebSocket::open()`:

```
QObject::connect(&sock,
                 &QWebSocket::sslErrors,
                 &sock,
                 static_cast<void(QWebSocket::*)(const QList<QSslError>&)>(&QWebSocket::ignoreSslErrors),
                 Qt::DirectConnection);
```

But the error is still happening. What's wrong?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9, added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a normal callback and then handle errors in it:

```
    QObject::connect(&sock,
                     &QWebSocket::sslErrors,
                     this,
                     &MyClass::sslError,
                     Qt::DirectConnection);

...

void MyClass::sslError(const QList<QSslError>& errors)
{
    // Here QWebSocket::ignoreSslErrors() can be called.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have this, still get "The host name did not match any of the valid hosts for this certificate" and then socket closes

Comment: Now it passes the SSL, but right away it closes connection and says "Connection closed by remote host". Server-side is NodeJS websocket server using "ws" package

Comment: @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9, so it blames NodeJS.